# SQL Query which selects data from the last 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I need to create a SQL query which selects the data which was recorded in the last 15 minutes.

I have a table in my database which records a value every time that you cross a laser. The table contains the columns ID, Date and Time (date and time are separate columns) the other columns dont really for what I am trying to do

Every time you cross the scanner a new row is created. which records the time and date, how am I able to count the number of rows which were created in the last 15 minutes, 30 minutes and an hour?
I'm guessing it will be the same sort of thing for the different times so 1 example should be fine thank you!

[image: Table Data]

Comment: To stop any confusion the last column is a foreign key so dont worry about this

Comment: mysql ??? oracle ??? sql server ???

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar mysql but does it really matter?

Comment: Yes off course.......

Comment: @LukeRayner this is where it matters... all datetime functions are different on different platforms.

Comment: @Hogan thank you for actually telling me why unlike the other guy

Comment: @LukeRayner yep, in MSSQL you say `now()` in DB2 you say `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`, etc

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select * from YourTable  where
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,concat(`Date`,' ',`Time`),NOW()) < 15
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af81c/1)

Comment: would this work if it was 00:03 would it still get the values from the day before? Im guessing it would I am just checking

Comment: @LukeRayner - yes, timestamp includes the date.

Comment: @LukeRayner hmm... now updated with single quotes and date+time

Comment: It is literally displaying everything in my database

Comment: @LukeRayner Added Fiddle too

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `Date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my sql query that will give you last 15 minutes of record.

In your table it seems two different field for date and time so combine them into datetime and than compare with current datetime

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

make 15 minutes in one variable and you can pass whatever minutes and get result accordingly..

Hope this will help.